# add a breakline in tooltip reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to add a breakline in tooltip in reactjs yet not working. Here is my attempt

```
<Tooltip placement="right" isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} target="TooltipExample" toggle={this.toggleTooltip}>
         line one {\n}
          line two

        </Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. I cannot test it immediately but I think this will work.

```
{"\n"}

<Tooltip placement="right" isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} target="TooltipExample" toggle={this.toggleTooltip}>
     line one {"\n"}
      line two

    </Tooltip>
```

EDIT: "~" delete, didn't intended to add it.

EDIT:
Did you try just adding `<br />`?

```
 <Tooltip placement="right" isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} target="TooltipExample" toggle={this.toggleTooltip}>
     line one <br />
      line two

    </Tooltip>
```

Comment: now im getting `line one ~ line two` both on the same line

Comment: Hmm sorry to hear that, thought it work on tooltips